# Extract json fields and write them into a csv with python

Tags: python, json, csv

I've got a very big json with multiple fields and I want to extract just some of them and then write them into a csv.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

import csv

data_file = open("book_data.json", "r")
values = json.load(data_file)
data_file.close()

with open("book_data.csv", "wb") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for data in values:
         value = data["identifier"]
         value = data["authors"]
         for key, value in data.iteritems():
               wr.writerow([key, value])
```

It gives me this error:

```
File "json_to_csv.py", line 22, in <module>
wr.writerow([key, value])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But I give the utf-8 encoding on the top, so I don't know what's wrong there.

Thanks

Comment: At which line is the error ?

Comment: File "json_to_csv.py", line 22, in <module>
    wr.writerow([key, value])

I'll add that.

Comment: try https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode the data:

```
wr.writerow([key.encode("utf-8"), value.encode("utf-8")])
```

The difference is equivalent to:

```
In [8]: print u'\u2019'.encode("utf-8")
’

In [9]: print str(u'\u2019')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-4e3ad09ee31b> in <module>()
----> 1 print str(u'\u2019')

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If you have a mixture of strings and lists and values, you can use *issinstance* to check what you have, if you have a list iterate over and encode:

```
with open("book_data.csv", "wb") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for data in values:
         for key, value in data.iteritems():
               wr.writerow([key, ",".join([v.encode("utf-8") for v in value]) if isinstance(value, list) else value.encode("utf8")])
```

To just write the three columns `creator, contributor` and `identifier`, just pull the data using the keys:

```
import csv

with open("book_data.csv", "wb") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for dct in values:
        authors = dct["authors"]
        wr.writerow((",".join(authors["creator"]).encode("utf-8"),
                     "".join(authors["contributor"]).encode("utf-8"),
                     dct["identifier"].encode("utf-8")))
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, bu now it gives me:

  File "json_to_csv.py", line 22, in <module>
    wr.writerow([key.encode("utf-8"), value.encode("utf-8")])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Do you have some values that are lists?

Comment: I've got values in the json like:

"authors": {"contributor": ["FORBES, Walter."], "creator": ["A. A."]}

Comment: OK, do you have all lists or a mixture? Also do you really want to be writing the data as lists?

Comment: A mixture, for instance identifier are just: 

"identifier": "000000206"

Comment: The edit should work for both, I used str.join instead of writing the list data as the str representation of itself as that will make parsing a lot easier

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.
Anyway, now it gives me that: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'.

It's becoming ridiculous, sorry ^^'

Comment: Can you add a small sample of the json to pastebin?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3C2tjP87

I think I need to add "elif isinstace (value, dict)"

Comment: We do need to add more logic but what format should the dict be put into your csv? Even in your dict you have a `{}` as a value.

Comment: I think the problem is "imgs", I don't need that, isn't there a way to tell "ignore this"? 

Sorry for bothering you so much.

Comment: Yep, I am off my comp now but I will edit when I get back on.

Comment: @LaraM., what fields do you actually want?

Comment: It's ok just creator, contributor and identifier.

Comment: @LaraM. There can be more than one author per book and also more than one contributor I presume?

Comment: Cool, then for multiple authors, contributors you will have a comma separated string which will be parsed as a single value when you read the file.

Comment: Thanks a multiple times!!